# NavigationDrawerActivity with BottomNavigationActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-bottomnav

I am trying to use NavigationDrawerActivity with a BottomNavigationActivity.
I have implemented NavigationDrawerActivity(Separate) first and saved BottomNavigationActivity(Separate) in HomeActivity but a black screen comes out while running app, with no errors!

My HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SearchFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
            break;

    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    return true;
}
}
```

Code for My HomeFragment consisting BottomNavigationView

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

View view;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
    return view;
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.tours:
                        selectedFragment = new ToursFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.hotel:
                        selectedFragment = new HotelFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.maps:
                        selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                        break;
                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                return true;
            }
        };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to use Navigation Drawer Activity with BottomNavigationActivity in this code and wanted to show BottomNavigationActivity in only one fragment.
I solved this problem, but first we forget HomeFragment, I deleted almost everything except View there.
I put BottomNavigationActivity with Navigation Drawer Activity in one Activity
Here is my xml from HomeActivity (i.e. it is MainActivity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>


    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_helder"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>



And submitted to HomeActivity to BottomNavigationActivity
setVisibility (View.GONE);





public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(toolbar, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    toolbar.setTitle("Paris Tours                                         ");

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new ToursFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_view);
    }

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    //I added this if statement to keep the selected fragment when rotating the device
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_bottom,
                new ToursFragment()).commit();
    }

}


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.tours:
                        selectedFragment = new ToursFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.hotel:
                        selectedFragment = new HotelFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.maps:
                        selectedFragment = new MapsFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.taxi:
                        selectedFragment = new TaxiFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_bottom,
                        selectedFragment).commit();

                return true;
            }
        };

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SearchFragment()).commit();
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new FavouriteFragment()).commit();
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.tours:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SettingsFragment()).commit();
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    return true;
}
```

}